# ngx-booptstrap: What are main differences in between ngx-booptstrap version 3.x.x and 4.x.x

Tags: angular, version, ngx-bootstrap

I am working on project Angular 6 where datepicker throws an error when used from ngx-bootstrap version 4.3.0.

> `Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.`

Well I learned that versions of typescript , angular and rxjs should be in sync (which are if I am not mistaken ) and that I can solve issues with ngx-bootstrap to modify file in node folder, which is not working solution for my case.

```
typescript@2.9.2
```

rxjs@6.2.2
@angular/cli@6.2.9

As potential solution for others who have same issue, I downgraded ngx-bootstrap to version 3.3.0 and that is fine now build works properly and datepicker is not UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY as was case with ngx-bootstrap version 4.x.

**Now the question**: I see both ngx-bootstrap versions support Bootstrap 3 and 4. I was not able to locate change log so wondering if anyone can help providing link or simple tell the differences and what is potential downside of downgrading version 4.x to 3.x ?

Note: it's a huge existing project limited with Angular version 6.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can find changelogs [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/releases?after=v4.3.0). I've already sorted it for you, and, you will see 4.2.0 and lower.
Also, you can check [CHANGELOG.MD](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md)

Actually, I can't really say, what kind of breaking change has been merged, which required a new version. There were position & adaptive changes, also, a bunch of changes, related to CI and build process, so, maybe, 4.0.0 was created because of that.